# Codeigniter Pagination links not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am having a problem with the pagination links.

I routed them, and I end up doing:

```
$route['blog/(:num)'] = "page/blog/$1";
```

at my **view**, I did

```
<?php foreach ($links as $link) { echo $link; } ?>
```

and at my *page* **controller**

```
public function blog(){

    //GET SITE TITLE
     $query = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('id' => 1));
      foreach($query->result() as $rows)    {                             
          $data['site_title'] = 'Blog &middot; ' . $rows->value;                           
     }

     //PAGINATE ITEMS   
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;      
            $config['num_links'] = 5;
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('blog/');
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->pagination_model->count_posts();
            $config['per_page'] = 2;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<nav><ul class="pagination">';          
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></nav>';          
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li><span aria-hidden="true">';
            $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';         
            $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['first_link'] = 'First';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li><span aria-hidden="true">';
            $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span></li>'; 

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            if($this->uri->segment(2)){
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ;
              }
            else{
                   $page = 1;
            }
            $data["results"] = $this->pagination_model->fetch_posts($config["per_page"], $page);
            $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

    $this->load->view('blog', $data);

}
```

So far, the pagination is working, yet, the links isn't. Its active state stays on page 1 and the next and previous links isn't working.
I can't figure out the culprit.

**EDIT:**

So I manage to edit the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('page/blog');
if($this->uri->segment(3)){
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
              }
            else{
                   $page = 1;
            }
```

and now it is working. However, I need the URL to be `mysite.com/blog/$the_pagination_id`